# Got `AttributeError` from `from_pymc3` of ArviZ

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, arviz

I am learning Bayesian inference by the book `Bayesian Analysis with Python`. However, when using `plot_ppc`, I got `AttributeError` and the warning

/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/kaggle/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymc3/sampling.py:1689: UserWarning: samples parameter is smaller than nchains times ndraws, some draws and/or chains may not be represented in the returned posterior predictive sample
warnings.warn(

The model is

```py
shift = pd.read_csv('../data/chemical_shifts.csv')

with pm.Model() as model_g:
    μ = pm.Uniform('μ', lower=40, upper=70)
    σ = pm.HalfNormal('σ', sd=10)
    y = pm.Normal('y', mu=μ, sd=σ, observed=shift)
    trace_g = pm.sample(1000, return_inferencedata=True)
```

If I used the following codes

```py
with model_g:
    y_pred_g = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace_g, 100, random_seed=123)
    data_ppc = az.from_pymc3(trace_g.posterior, posterior_predictive=y_pred_g) # 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'report'
```

I got 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'report'.

If I used the following codes

```py
with model_g:
    y_pred_g = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace_g, 100, random_seed=123)
    data_ppc = az.from_pymc3(trace_g, posterior_predictive=y_pred_g) # AttributeError: 'InferenceData' object has no attribute 'report'
```

I got AttributeError: 'InferenceData' object has no attribute 'report'.

ArviZ version: 0.11.2
PyMC3 Version: 3.11.2
Aesara/Theano Version: 1.1.2
Python Version: 3.9.6
Operating system: MacOS Big Sur
How did you install PyMC3: conda

Answer (score 5):

You are passing `return_inferancedata=True` to `pm.sample()`, which according to the [PyMC3 documentation](https://docs.pymc.io/api/inference.html#module-pymc3.sampling) will return an `InferenceData` object rather than a `MultiTrace` object.

```
return_inferencedatabool, default=False

    Whether to return the trace as an arviz.InferenceData (True) object or a MultiTrace (False) Defaults to False, but we’ll switch to True in an upcoming release.
```

The `from_pymc3` function, however, [expects a `MultiTrace` object](https://arviz-devs.github.io/arviz/api/generated/arviz.from_pymc3.html).

The good news is that `from_pymc3` returns an `InferenceData` object, so you can solve this in one of two ways:

1. The easiest solution is to simply remove the `from_pymc3` calls, since it returns `InferenceData`, which you already have due to `return_inferencedata=True`.
2. Set `return_inferencedata=False` (you can also remove that argument, but the documentation states that in the future it will default to `True`, so to be future proof it's best to explicitly set it to `False`). This will return a `MultiTrace` which can be passed to `from_pymc3`.

Comment: Thank you, Nikolas. The 2nd solution worked. However, I still would like to try the 1st solution.

Comment: The 1st solution also worked. Thank you again !